# How to find the format of a disk volume

Tags: macos, cocoa, disk

I am updating a backup utility I have written and have on the Mac App store.

In a Macintosh Cocoa application, how do I find how a disk volume is formatted? The only official thing I find, is doing a GetResourceValue: for 'NSURLVolumeLocalizedFormatDescriptionKey', but that is language dependent.

My utility does not support volumes formatted for FAT32. My utility needs to do special handling for XSan drives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`statfs(2)` will give you a non-localized name:

```
struct statfs volinfo;
if(statfs("/path/to/your/volume", &volinfo) != 0)
{
  perror("statfs");
  return -1;
}

fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", volinfo.f_fstypename);
```

See `/System/Library/Filesystems` for the names that will be returned in `f_fstypename`.

Comment: Works! I notice that the "MobileBackups" iCloud drive is "mtmfs" which is not one of the listed file systems. When converting the url.path to a C String, what encoding do I use? I'm using 'NSASCIIStringEncoding'.

Comment: Use `[[url path] fileSystemRepresentation]`; cf. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered but I'll throw my 2 cents in...

```
/sbin/mount | grep acfs | awk '{print $3}'
```

This outputs

```
/Volumes/XsanVolumeName1
/Volumes/XsanVolumeName2
```

Comment: I needed to find out the *format* of a particular volume, not the other way around and I needed to do it in Objective C. You're showing me the volumes that use a particular file system—interesting idea, but it wasn't what I was looking for..